# How can I set a timer to wait until iframe src is set in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to tell an iframe to wait x amount of seconds before calling the url in the src attribute? What I have right now immediately makes a call onload. I know for `meta` tags, there is a `content` attribute that you can set to wait x amount of seconds? Does iframe have something similar? Or do I have to use javascript to wait and make a reference to the iframe id or name?

```
"<iframe src="/api/test"/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive the code below will give you the result you want....

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // function to set the source (src) of the iframe....
    function myframe(){
        var frame = document.getElementById("iframe").src = "fileName.html";
     }
     // call the function 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) after page load...
     setTimeout(myframe, 3000);
</script>

     <iframe id="iframe" src="" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```